# Calling web API's via SAP Web Dispatcher from c#

Tags: c#, saprfc

I call a number of BAPI's and FM's using RFC calls to SAP using c#.

I would now like to convert these calls to connect and call then via SAP Web Dispatcher.

Does anyone know how the API calls will work for a given BAPI?
I.e. will all SAP FM's have a corresponding web method, or is there a generic API wrapper that can be used to call all existing RFC Function Modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're lazy, there's a deprecated service `/sap/bc/soap/rfc` with a specific format in the body of requests and responses (not documented).

This [blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/02/13/calling-rfc-enabled-function-modules-over-http-from-external-application/) talks about this format.

I say deprecated because it's usually advised to migrate from BAPIs to dedicated APIs/OData services.

Comment: Thanks! Are there a way to know what the API/OData service is for a given BAPI? Some mapping between the 2 or perhaps a table in SAP that will indicate the corresponding service?

Comment: I think SAP did not publish such an equivalence table.